# Template object field enforcement

Tags: templates, struct, go, interface, embedding

Go provides great build in HTML templating functionality, however for me it is important that I can ensure certain fields will always be available to templates in my application. A good example of this is a title field, which needs to be shown on every HTML page.

Given the following pages:
`Home`
`Register`
`Contact`

I would likely create the following objects for the templating system:
`HomePage` struct
`RegisterPage` struct
`ContactPage` struct

Is there a recommended way to ensure that the structs for each page have certain fields available to them?

Ideally I would implement this through Polymorphism, but that isn't officially supported in Go. The alternative, [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) doesn't appear to have any enforcement, i.e all of the child structs *can* embed a parent struct but don't *have to*.

Let me know if I haven't expressed my question clearly enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing a template does not enforce anything to the parameters, [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) accepts a value of type `interface{}`.

You are the one creating the `HomePage`, `RegisterPage` and `ContactPage` structs. What stops you from embedding a `BasePage` struct with the required fields? Are you worried you will forget about it? You will notice it at the first testing, I wouldn't worry about that:

```
type BasePage struct {
    Title string
    Other string
    // other required fields...
}

type HomePage struct {
    BasePage
    // other home page fields...
}

type RegisterPage struct {
    BasePage
    // other register page fields...
}
```

If you want from code to check if page structs embed the `BasePage`, I recommend another way: interfaces.

```
type HasBasePage interface {
    GetBasePage() BasePage
}
```

Example `HomePage` that implements it:

```
type HomePage struct {
    BasePage
    // other home page fields...
}

func (h *HomePage) GetBasePage() BasePage {
    return h.BasePage
}
```

Now obviously only pages that have a `GetBasePage()` method can be passed as a value of `HasBasePage`:

```
var page HasBasePage = &HomePage{} // Valid, HomePage implements HasBasePage
```

If you don't want to use interfaces, you can use the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package to check if a value is a struct value and if it embeds another interface. Embedded structs appear and can be accessed like ordinary fields e.g. with [`Value.FieldByName()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName), with the type name being the field name.

Example code using `reflect` to check if a value embeds `BasePage`:

```
page := &HomePage{BasePage: BasePage{Title: "Home page"}}

v := reflect.ValueOf(page)
if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    v = v.Elem()
}
if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
    fmt.Println("Error: not struct!")
    return
}
bptype := reflect.TypeOf(BasePage{})
bp := v.FieldByName(bptype.Name()) // "BasePage"
if !bp.IsValid() || bp.Type() != bptype {
    fmt.Println("Error: struct does not embed BasePage!")
    return
}

fmt.Printf("%+v", bp)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/m9EgovLcHy)):

```
{Title:Home page Other:}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and insightful answer!